# I want to use Algolia to fetch products by SKU

Tags: reactjs, magento2, algolia

I've got a product that has related product data, which gives me the object below:

```
[{
  link_type: "related"
  linked_product_sku: "gcn-202-1"
  linked_product_type: "configurable"
  position: 3
  sku: "EMBN-101-CL-BK-CY"
}]
```

The linked_product_sku is the related product. There might be multiple products in the array and I'm wondering how I would fetch that product data via the sku using Algolia.

I want to use Algolia instead of changing the data we are getting from magento because Algolia is so fast, I just can't see on their documentation how you would go about doing this.

Hoping someone has ran into the same issue.

https://community.algolia.com/react-instantsearch/

Important to know I'm doing this in React.

Answer (score 1):

From your description it sounds like `linked_product_sku` will be an array of values. You intend to use this array of values to retrieve objects from Algolia, and not for display to the user. Is that correct?

To make sure you get the exact object you want from Algolia, I would suggest referencing the `objectID` of these linked products (you would therefore have to update your existing records).

Your old object looked like this:

```
[{
  link_type: "related"
  linked_product_sku: "gcn-202-1"
  linked_product_type: "configurable"
  position: 3
  sku: "EMBN-101-CL-BK-CY"
}]
```

Your updated object might look like this:

```
[{
  link_type: "related"
  linked_product_objectIDs: ["1234", "5678"]
  linked_product_type: "configurable"
  position: 3
  sku: "EMBN-101-CL-BK-CY"
}]
```

There is no magic bullet to resolve your custom use-case, but in essence you could then use these `objectIDs` in a `filters` parameter of a `<Configure />` widget.

```
<Configure
    filters={'objectID:1234 OR objectID:5678'}
  />
```